# Quasiquoter concrete syntax for visible type application

Tags: haskell, syntax, template-haskell, quasiquotes

In the following snippet, the first argument to `foo`, `SNat @n`, is assembled manually:

```
[e|foo $(appTypeE (conE 'SNat) n')|]
  where
    n' = litT . numTyLit . fromIntegral $ n
```

Is there concrete TH quasiquoter syntax for this? I.e. I'd like to write something like

```
[e|foo (SNat @$n')|]
```

but that is seemingly parsed as if I was applying an infix operator `($@)`:

```
> runQ [e|foo (SNat @$n')|]
AppE (VarE foo) (InfixE (Just (ConE SNat)) (UnboundVarE @$) (Just (VarE n')))
```

Interestingly, the `[e| |]` quasi-quoter does seem to support the concrete syntax for non-quasi  visible type application:

```
> runQ [e|foo (SNat @5)|]
AppE (VarE foo) (AppTypeE (ConE SNat) (LitT (NumTyLit 5)))
```

Comment: You should here pass the `[e|foo|]` part to the quasi quoter I think, so `runQ [| [e|foo (SNat @$n')|] |]`, unless I am missing something?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure what you mean? The eventual result of my TH macro should be as if the user has written `foo (SNat @5)` in his code etc. The `runQ` invocation is just to test how the `[e| |]` quasi-quoter parses `@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses.

```
let n  = 5
    n' = litT $ numTyLit $ fromIntegral n
in  runQ [e| foo (SNat @($n')) |]
-- ==>
AppE (UnboundVarE foo) (AppTypeE (UnboundVarE SNat) (LitT (NumTyLit 5)))
```

A space also works, but I wouldn't use one:

```
[e| foo (SNat @ $n') |]
```